# Calling window for Mac Whatsapp Desktop is blank

Tags: mac, desktop

When making or receiving a call on the Mac desktop version of Whatsapp, the small window that opens with the contact info and the hang up button, opens black & blank.

We dumped & reinstalled the desktop app from Apple's App Store, and it worked properly once, but then not again.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with Whatsapp.  Did you query their support channels?

Comment: Their Help FAQs were unhelpful and rather general. I could find nothing about specific display issues. Maybe I'm missing stuff - if you've gotta link to something other than their Help FAQs I'd sure appreciate a pointer. TIA!

Comment: I'm not a WhatsApp user (I much prefer [Signal](https://signal.org)), but you can check out/post on forums like  the [WhatsApp Messenger](https://androidforums.com/apps/whatsapp-messenger.301/) or on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsapp/).  Don't delete your question here, though.  Someone may still run across this and post an answer, but you'll likely find more people on those forums.  If you do, post an answer here.  Ping me and I'll up vote it for you!

Comment: Same problem here - I removed all Whatsapp folders and re-installed it - and it still doesn't work on my Mac

Comment: Me too. It only works when the app is reopened for once. I'm still looking for the origin of the problem, but I think it's a whatsapp bug.

Comment: Same problem here, I tried everything, delete the App, delete cache, reinstall same results. I updated the macOS to 13.2 and the problem persists, I have come to think that the application is compromised, will try with a new user profile.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juqFo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juqFo.png) Same issues still happening. Installed and uninstalled, deleted all files using Clean my MAC and still issue prevails.

Comment: After updating to a newer Whatsapp version the issue seems to be solved.

Comment: Same problem here.  It just loads a blank window.